# __block variables behavior with nested blocks

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks, retain

I'm having a problem with __block variables in nested blocks. My question is, should a code like the following work?

```
__block NSString* s = nil;
[self methodWithBlock:^
 {
    s = [self methodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedString];
    [self methodWithBlock:^
     {
         [NSLog @"%d", s.length];
     }];
 }];
```

I assumed the inner block retained `s` but that doesn't seem to be the case in my code. I get a *"message sent to deallocated instance"* when accessing `s` in the inner block. If I retain s when I assign it (`s = [[self methodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedString] retain];`), it works fine.

Of course, that's not my actual code, which is more complex, but I just want to know if that minimal example should work fine. If so, I need to look for my problem elsewhere.

Comment: "If I retain s when I assign it (...), it works fine." Yes, that's what you need to do. Also note that if you don't release it when you're done with it, it will be leaked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I assume that you don't use ARC.) From the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> In manual reference counting mode, `__block id x;` has the effect of not
>   retaining `x`.

So your assumption is wrong, the block does not retain `s`. You have to retain it if
`methodWithBlock` works asynchronously.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know __block worked differently in ARC vs manual ref counting. Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoRuggiero: You are welcome. - Yes, this is a subtle difference. Fortunately, I can use ARC in all projects :-)

Comment: @MarianoRuggiero: yes, and in fact, in MRC, using `__block` is the only way to make the block not retain a captured variable. In ARC they instead use `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained` for this.